# c++ Удаление повторяющихся элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Ни как не пойму, как сделать это удаление повторяющихся элементов, помогите. Видно я совсем чушь какую-то написал после ввода массива :) Помогите, как нужно правильно удалять

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        int size, m ,i;
        cin >> size;
        int *arr = new int[size];

        for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
            cin >> arr[m];   
        }

        for (m = 0; m < size; m++) { // 
            for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1]) {  
                    delete[] arr;
                    size--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В денном решении все одинаковые сдвигаются в хвост массива с уменьшением длины.

Хвост можно обрезать, а можно не учитывать.

```
for (m = 0; m < size; m++) { // 
        cout << arr[m] << endl;
        for (i = m+1; i < size; i++) {
            if (arr[m] == arr[i]) {
                for (int k = i; k < size - 1; k++) {
                    arr[k] = arr[k + 1];
                }
                size--;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможен вариант решения через запись уникальных значений в новый массив.
Приведен код, когда ВСЕ повторяющиеся значения удаляются.
При необходимости можно переработать код для удаления всех повторяющихся кроме первого (проверять все значения изначального массива с финальным массивом, а не с первичным).

```
void main()
{
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int firstSize = 0;
    int outSize = 0;
    int controlNumb = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    std::cin >> firstSize;
    int* arrayFirst = new int[firstSize];
    int* arrayOut = new int[firstSize];

    for (int count = 0; count < firstSize; count++)
        std::cin >> arrayFirst[count]; 
    for (int count = 0; count < firstSize; count++)
        arrayOut[count]=0;
    
    for (i = 0; i < firstSize; i++) //Для каждого числа в массиве
    {
        controlNumb = 1;//Обновляем контрольное значение
        for (k = 0; k < firstSize; k++) //проверяем каждое значение массива
            if ((k!=i) & (arrayFirst[i] == arrayFirst[k])) controlNumb = 0;  //кроме него самого, и если какое то из них совпало, присваиваем контрольному значению 0
        if (controlNumb) //если контрольное значение осталось 1, то прибавляем 1 к условному размеру Конечного массива и записываем в конец уникальное число
        {
            outSize++;
            arrayOut[outSize - 1] = arrayFirst[i];
        }
    }
    if (!outSize) //если условный размер финального массива остался равен нулю
        std::cout << "В массиве отсутствуют уникальные значения";
    else 
    for (int count = 0; count < outSize; count++) //вывожу значения финального массива через пробел
        std::cout << arrayOut[count] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения Вашей задачи есть много вариантов.

ИМХО работайте с вектором. Скопируйте Ваши данные в вектор

```
int *arr = new int[10];
std::vector<int> v{arr, arr + 10};
...
if (arr) {
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Для Вас я привел 2 варианта решения задачи :

1) С предварительной сортировкой и использование std::unique

2) С сохранением последовательности

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


int main() {
    // Вариант для последовательности с предворительной сортировкой
    std::vector<int> v{7,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,4,5,4,5,6,7};
    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(last, v.end()); 

    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Вариант для несоритрованной последовательности
    std::vector<int> v2{7,6,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,4,5,4,5,6,7};
    std::copy(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (auto it{std::begin(v2)}; it != std::end(v2); it = std::next(it)) {
        for (auto sub_it{std::next(it)}; sub_it != std::end(v2); sub_it = std::next(sub_it)) {
            if (*sub_it == *it) {
                v2.erase(sub_it);
                --sub_it;
            }
        }
    }
    std::copy(std::begin(v2), std::end(v2), std::ostream_iterator<int>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```